# What does $\Bbb{Z}_{18}$ mean in this question?

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to solve this question

> Let $G=\Bbb{Z}_{18}$ and $H$ a subgroup of G generated by $3$, Talk about normal subgroups and coset multiplication then find the cosets $(G/H,\bigotimes)$

Does $\Bbb{Z}_{18}$ mean $$\{0,1,2,3,...,16,17\}$$
or
$$\{1,a,a^2,...,a^{16},a^{17}\}$$
where $a$ is the generator of $G$.

If it is the second the definition then what does $a$ equal to here?

I am just confused if I am supposed to use the multiplication or addition here.

Comment: I think $\mathbb Z_{18}$ means integers modulo $18$

Comment: Yes, normally the first option.

Comment: @Théophile, so when calculating the cosets do I use the addition or multiplication i.e $g +H$ or $g.H$ where $g\in G$?

Comment: What is the book you are using?

Comment: When it says "generated by $3$" I deduce that the second option is no good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am looking Your first option sounds good to me. if your $Z_{18}$ is $\Bbb{Z}_{18}$.
and the cosets in  $\Bbb{Z}_{18}/H$ are

$0+H=\{0,3,6,9,12,15\}$,

$1+H=\{1,4,7,10,13,16\}$  and so on. Can you complete it?

Comment: Yes, $Z_{18}$ is $\Bbb{Z}_{18}$. So when calculating the cosets do I use the addition too or do I use multiplication i.e $g +H$ or $g.H$ where $g\in G$?

Comment: addition i.e., $g+H$.

Comment: But why does $\bigotimes$ appear in $(G/H,\bigotimes)$. Doesn't this mean multiplication?

Comment: This is the modulo addition.

Comment: I think $H=\{0,3,6,9,12,15\}$.

Comment: @gbd yup, I forgot.

Comment: @Aman Pandey check that you are saying , costs in Z₁₈/H, but it is not ok, you have to say cosets of H in Z₁₈.

Comment: @AmanPandey, Is $0+H=H$ a coset too. Since $0\in G$

Comment: @gnd I wrote so.

Comment: @Subhajit Sorry! I can't get you. Well!Thanks  for your suggestion.

Comment: @gbd which book are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Both are same. In the second group if you replace a by $1$ and use the operation of addition modulo $18$, then you get $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$. The notation $a^n$ means you apply the group operation on $a$, $n$ times. Both the sets you mentioned will be isomorphic if you use the map $1$ goes to $a$. So both are isomorphic. We generally use the first set you mentioned under addition modulo $18$ as it is easier to handle.

If you are talking about the normal subgroups of $G/H$:

As far as the quotient is concerned, $G/H$ has three elements and hence is a cyclic group (thus abelian) of order $3$. It is of the form $\{ H, 1+H, 2+H \}$. Since it is abelian, all the subgroups are normal. But since the order of group is $3$ it has only two subgroups $\{e\}$ (where $e$ is the identity) and the group $G/H$ itself.

Comment: "\left\{" and "\right\}".

Comment: Simpler yet, just `\{` and `\}`. Use `\left` and `\right` when size is an issue, e.g., if there are fractions or nested parentheses.

Comment: Yes. Will edit soon.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Z}_{18}$ is the set of integers mod $18$. It is a group of order $18$ defined under modulo addition.

$$\mathbb{Z}_{18} = \{0, 1, 2, 3,..., 17\}$$

Notice that we stop at $17$. This is because $0$ is the identity element. If you're not familiar with modulo arithmetic, you may also be confused about how this group is closed under addition. After all, isn't $1+17=18$? Well, in this group, $17$ is the inverse of $1$. So $1+17=0$. Furthermore, $$2+16=0$$ $$3+15=0$$
and so on.

To answer your second question, factor (quotient) groups are defined under coset multiplication, which is defined as follows:

$$(aH)(bH) = (a\cdot b)H$$

where $\cdot$ is the binary operation of the original group.

Comment: Do you mean I should use  $g+H$ or $g.H$, g∈G when calculating the cosets?

Comment: Well, when you're calculating the cosets, you're going to use the "original" group's binary operation. Take an element in $G$ and add it to each element in $H$. Repeat this process for each element in $G$. Some of your cosets will be identical, so you don't have to rewrite these cosets. Now, the group $G/H$ is defined under coset multiplication. This is what I've defined in my answer.